# Executing programs from main argument

Tags: c, fork, exec

I want to make a program that executes programs from the main argument.
Let's say I have the program `progr1.c` and `progr2.c` running . Now I compile the program `progr3.c` using the other two programs as arguments. This should be the result :

> ./progr3 progr1 progr2
>
> Result of progr1
>
> Result of progr2

This is what I have done so far :

```
void main (int args , char **s) {

int  i , x , status;

if (args >= 2) {

    x = fork ();

    for ( i = 1 ; i < args ; i++) {

           if (x == 0) {
            execv (s[1],s);
           }
          else
         {
            wait (&status);
            _exit(i);
         }
          x= fork();
      }
  }
  _exit(0);
 }
```

This code only does the output of the first argument program. So Im guessing `fork()` and `execv()` are not working together as I wanted them to . How can I change the program inorder to do what I want?

Comment: [`int main()`](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmainbooks.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

```
        execv (s[1],s); // That should have been s[i]
```

`prog3` is replaced by `prog1`. Hence, the logic of `prog3` is lost.

You need to use `fork` and then `execv` on the child process if you want to retain the logic of `prog3`.

If you are interested in just the output of `prog1` and `prog2`, you can use `system(s[i])`

**Update**

A working example using `fork`.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   char* programs[] = {"/usr/bin/ls", "/usr/bin/date"};
   char* args[] = {NULL, NULL};
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i )
   {
      int pid = fork();
      if ( pid )
      {
         // Child
         args[0] = programs[i];
         execv(programs[i], args);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: My mistake it should be a `i` instead of `1` . But it still only does the 1st program. Is there another error in the code @R Sahu ?

Comment: @JoséCunha, you misunderstand what `execv` does. Once you call it, the image of `prog3` is replaced by the image of `prog1`. Hence, `prog3` is not running any longer. That's why `prog2` never gets executed.

Comment: Oh Ok i got it. So basically, using any function of the `exec()` family it would change the image of the original program. How can I use this `execv` inorder to avoid changing the actual program? Could it be `fork()` the solution to avoid such thing @R Sahu ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use `fork` to preserve the original program.

Comment: Ok so I tried different things. I used `system` and it works. But I have been struggling on matching the `fork` and `execv` part.
I tried using `fork` outside the cycle , checked if it is a child and then `execv` and it didn't work. I used inside the cycle and I got the same output. How can I implement it straight? (sorry for the repetitive questions @R Sahu)

Answer (score 0):

`execv` *replaces* the current process with the command specified.

Instead, use `system` to create a new process. No need for forking either:

```
int system(const char *command)
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that function @dovetalk . But I used it and it still doesn't work right. How can implement it?